# Measure a lithium-ion battery internal resistance curve over time

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, measurement, internal-resistance

I am making a battery tester for lithium ion batteries. I want to measure the internal resistance, voltage and current.

[image]
[image]

I am skeptical of my results. On [batteryuniversity](https://batteryuniversity.com/article/how-does-internal-resistance-affect-performance), I read that the internal resistance curve should start and end with higher resistance. The resistance should reach the lowest point in the middle of the curve.

I am using LFP18650, 9 V, and 1500 mAh battery packs.

As a quick review of the measurement of the Ri: Ri= U1-U2/I1

- Load enabled for 19 seconds
- Load disabled for 3 seconds

**U1:** measure voltage very close to the last moment of the 3 seconds*

- load enabled
- waiting 500 milliseconds

**U2**: measure the voltage very close to the last moment of the 500 milliseconds.

**I2:** current measurement at the exact moment of the U2.

Why am  I getting this result? Totally not similar to a u-curve.

Comment: How much sag during load, slew rate and time of ADC is important

Comment: @winny 500 milliseconds (time interval), between "with load" and "without".

Comment: Thank you! Is 500 ms off + 500 ms on the total cycle time? If yes, that time constant may be too short to give a correct V1. Have you tried to do a step response of the battery to find out its RC time constant?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 thank you, I am using just python code for a programmable load east Tester ET5410 and charger Velleman connected to my PC. Good to know (I am not an electrical engineer) I am a software engineer ;)

Comment: @winny 19 s load enabled, then load disabled for 3 seconds measure V1 at the last moment of the 3 seconds. Load enabled again, waiting for 500 ms and measuring the V2 with the I2. and again the same loop

Comment: Your method of measuring Ri is OK, and gives 'correct' results until... what's going on at the right-hand side of the second graph, current is decreasing? Why is it not constant?

Comment: @BruceAbbott like the way while charging a lithium ion battery, using CC and CV. Do you mean that I should measure the Ri just in constant current mode?

Comment: _"Do you mean that I should measure the Ri just in constant current mode?"_ - Yes, all the way to low voltage cutoff.

Comment: Right, three seconds >> RC time constant of the battery. It’s not that causing the diminishing calculated resistance.

Comment: Khalil measure V at the beginning , middle and end of each 500 ms period to discover errors, then use a constant current load, not a constant voltage that later decays with the low state of charge  and thus neither CV or CC or CR .. warning  bad results

Comment: There are actually two ESR's and two C values for RC1=T and RC2 = T2 from double layer effects. So duration of pulse and delay time should be  short high current and long no current in seconds as dV/dt= Ic/C and C2 is ~ 10000 Farads for nom Li Ion 18650 but what is C1R1?

Comment: If you short a battery for <<1 second or less. Why does voltage return slowly from 0V?  The answer is C2R2

Comment: I would  increase current to max like 3A ? then extend Toff to 3 seconds and measure start middle end or until Vout returns to near previous voltage. This is how you can measure and compute T1 and T2 for ESR1C1 and ESR2C2 both series RC's in parallel. one is charged from the other in CC mode then in CV mode the smaller C catches up with the longer T time. but only for < 10% of total charge ctime.

Comment: You'll need some help with the formulae to convert Ah to coulomb counting to C1, C2 with separate slopes  for T1, T2  (p.s. there is also a T3)

Comment: Do you understand me? How can I explain how to measure these properly? A constant current pulse measured by voltage changes computes ESR directly V=ESR*CC pulse. The time intervals must measure over a longer period, at start middle and end to compute dV/dt= DeltaV/ESR/C = Ic/C.  Capiche? There are two ESR * C =T time constants at least. Questions? Think like Pease.